# how to select my first child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm having a bit of trouble selecting the first child in jQuery. I'm trying to do this to avoid having LOTS of if statements. Basically, you click on a button. This class selector is setup to handle the click in my JS. Once you go into the JS, I want to get the child of the item that was just clicked, but I'm not having any joy.

Here's what I have in my JS:

```
$('.itemClicked').click(function(){

var id = $(this).attr('id').first();
    // it can't find the method first() here. If I just find the id, I get the 
    // correct ID of what I just clicked.          

var test = id.first();
    // I tried the above to seperate the ID from the first() method request
    // no joy with this either.

test.toggleClass("icon-tick");
    // this is my ultimate aim, to toggle this icon-tick class on the item
    // clicked.

});
```

Thanks in advance if you can help me out here. I'm probably just doing something stupid but I'm struggling to realise what that is.

Answer (score 8):

Your current version doesn't work because `.attr('id')` just returns the ID as a string, not a jQuery object.  Also, `.first()` returns the first item from a jQuery collection, not their children.

So, you just want:

```
var test = $(this).children().first();
```

or:

```
var test = $('>:first-child', this);
```

or:

```
var test = $(this).children(':first');
```

or (on newer browsers):

```
var test = $(this.firstElementChild);
```

In a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/first-child-methods/edit) test with Chrome 25 the `.firstElementChild` method was incredibly fast, but it's not available on MSIE < 9.  The `.children()`.first()`was the fastest portable option, and the`>:first-child' method was very, very slow.

Comment: To be clear (as there is no concept such as "ID" in Javascript), his code is attempting to call a first() method on a string, is what attr() will return.

Comment: @mori57 thanks - clarified

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
$('.itemClicked').click(function(){
    $(':first-child',this).toggleClass('icon-tick');
});
```

is what you're after.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ySMLG/

Comment: I always forget that you can scope selectors like this. +1 for the reminder. :)

Comment: this code doesn't work if there's more than one level of elements below the click element because `$(sel, this)` is equivalent to `.find()` and _not_ to `.children()`.

Answer (score -2):

If all that you want to do is toggle the class "icon-tick" on the item that was click, then this will work:

```
$('.itemClick').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-tick');
});
```

The statement:

```
$(this).attr('id').first()
```

doesn't work because the attr() method returns the value of the attribute, not the jQuery object, so it is not chainable.

Comment: OP clearly stated that they wanted to toggle the class on the *first child of the item clicked*

Comment: No, in fact, the comment in the OP's code states "this is my ultimate aim, to toggle this icon-tick class on the item clicked." Nevertheless, the question is not entirely clear, so I prefaced my answer with an "If..."

Comment: @JamesTracy but _everyone_ knows that comments become out-of-date within 5s of them being added to the code...